# Finding values at intersection of two graphs

Tags: python-3.x

I have a somewhat complex mathematical function for which I want to find the meeting point of two graphs. I went through some answers but couldn't get what I wanted. Code below

```
from scipy.special import gamma, factorial

mu=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
b_value=[] 
N_0=8000 
c=3.78 
b=[9.922]*6  #straight line

for i in range (len(mu)):
     b = ((3.6*(c**3)*3.14*1000*N_0*(10**-6)/12)*gamma(6.01+mu[i]))/(6*3.14*c*N_0*(10**-  4)*gamma(4.67+mu[i]))**((6.01+mu[i])/(4.67+mu[i]))
     b_value.append(b)

plt.figure(570) 
plt.scatter(mu,b_value,color='r',lw='2',label = 'b_theoretical',marker="o")
plt.plot(mu,b,':',color='b',lw='2',label = 'b')
```

Basically I want to find the value of their intersection.Scatter plot can be plotted as line as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does `mu` refer to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all intersection points of graphs in a loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017155/how-to-find-all-intersection-points-of-graphs-in-a-loop-in-python)

Comment: I have edited by adding mu. No, the the link doesn't help. Thanks though