# Sympy - How to return fractions after using solve function

Tags: python, decimal, sympy, fractions

The title basically says my Question. How do I return a fraction after using the solve function from sympy.
I have tried using Rational() function and Fraction(). Are there any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, please, create some simple example code, so people get an idea of what you need.  Do you need an exact fraction from a symbolic expression? What would you expect when the result would be `pi`? Or do you need some approximation to some numeric expression?  To which precission? Also note that depending on the equations you're solving, the result of `solve` can have many different forms (dictionaries, lists, matrices, ....).

Comment: Maybe [How do I replace floats with rationals in a sympy expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005132/how-do-i-replace-floats-with-rationals-in-a-sympy-expression)

Comment: When you mention trying something, you should show that, and the results (wrong or not).  We want more evidence that you actually worked at this :)